# Abbreviations for Time Symbols

Tags: symbols

I believed I use to see that the symbols: " and ' were abbreviations for time... is that still the case? I am trained as an Engineer or it is possible that I am confusing it with the longitude/latitude. I know that they are symbols for height.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 3):

In addition to representing feet and inches, ' and " are also used for "minutes" and "seconds" respectively - whether this is in the context of latitude/longitude or in the context of time, although the latter is more [informal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute).

Comment: Yeah, it's less common to see `'` used for minutes of time and `"` used for seconds of time than it is to see those characters used for minutes and seconds of longitude/latitude.  I wouldn't say that either is "informal", but the audience for time values is broader than that for longitude/latitude values and hence less likely to be familiar with the notation.

Comment: I've seen it in timing contexts before, especially on stop watches with cheap displays.